# Extract a tar.xz in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, qt, tar, xz

I am writing a program that downloads tar.xz files from a server and extracts them in a certain place. I am struggling to find a away of extracting the tar.xz file in the certain place. I am using Qt so a more Qt-way of doing it would be useful, but I don't really mind.

Comment: +1 for making me curious about .xz which I hadn't ran across before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for archives in Qt. You can either have a look at the KDE library which offers support for virtual file systems or you can use `QProcess` to call `tar` directly. Use `-C <dir>` (uppercase C) to specify the directory to extract to.

[EDIT] There also is [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/) (BSD license).

Comment: I would prefere not to use QProcess because I would like my application to run on windows as well and using QProcess would mean I would have to ship with tar for windows. Maybe someone could give me a tutorial on liblzma.

Comment: That lib won't allow you to read the tar archive. If ".xz" is not a typo, then liblzma will only allow you to decompress the archive. But usually tar archives are compressed with bzip2 (.bz2) or gzip (.gz). For these, you probably need other libraries.

Comment: I believe I can use zlib to extract the tar, is this correct.

Comment: Yes but you have *two* containers inside of each other. You have the GZip container and inside of that a Tar container. Unzipping the file just gives you an uncompressed tar archive. How do you plan to read the files from that?

Comment: Not sure, it must be possible though because gnu tar can do it.

Comment: Then you must turn the source for tar into a library and link your code against it :-) Note that GNU tar is GPL so if you use that, your product will also be GPL'd.

Comment: I've found something called libtar that may help me.